# flutter - how to implement refresh indicator in Staggered GridView

Tags: flutter, staggered-gridview

I am using Staggered GridView package in Flutter. I am using `StaggeredGridView.extentBuilder` factory to show a grid of some cards.

I want to implement a refresh indicator when the user scroll above the top and rebuild the grid.

I have no idea how to implement that. Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your `StaggeredGridView` in a `RefreshIndicator` widget. You can give it a callback that refresh your item list:

```dart
return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => yourCallback(),
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(...));
```

Then, if the user scroll "above the top", a refresh spinner will be displayed and your callback called.